# Hexadecimal dump

Tags: binary, hex

```
Consider the following hexadecimal dump:

Offset    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
00000000 00 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E
00000010 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E
00000020 FE FE FF 01 01 01 00 ED 00 45 00 62 00 67 00 31
00000030 00 33 00 00 05 06 07 08 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

determine the sign and decimal value of the 16-bit little-endian signed

integer, which begins in the dump at the offset 21 hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

The 16-bit hex **FE FF** sequence corresponds to binary **11111110 11111111**.
These bits have been written *little-endian*, so the actual concatenated 16-bit binary is
the set of bits in reverse order.
Concatenated this becomes **0111111111111111**.
The first bit **0** denotes a positive (*signed*) number, so the decimal number represented is the decimal value of the remaining 15 bits, **32767**, the largest positively signed  number possible.